# AWS EC2 how to use pre-existing EBS volume as main bootable disk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a EBS volume from a previous T2 instance, which contains operating system, mysql installation, created users and all configurations.

For launching a new instance (T2), how to use
the pre-existing EBS volume as main bootable disk so that we have the operating system, apps and all configurations? This would save us days of time and efforts.

For a business application, should we choose T2 or T3?

Comment: can you create a snapshot and then an AMI from that ? will that work ?

Comment: When launching an instance, there is no place to select my own AMI.

Comment: I did not get you you cannot find your AMI in your private AMI's ?

Comment: Thanks can I add it as an answer and kindly accept it.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/639537/booting-an-ec2-instance-from-an-existing-ebs-volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed you can perform the below steps to create an EC2 instance from a pre existing EBS volume.

- Create a snapshot from the EBS volume.
- Create an AMI from the same.
- Look for the AMI in your private AMI.
- Create the EC2 instance with desired instance-type from this AMI.
- Also you need to care for the EBS volumes with this new EC2 instance with minimum EBS volume size etc.

Please let me know.